# Python Regex works for match at the beginning, but not at end

Tags: python, regex

I am fairly new at python, but have used regex for a while.  What am I missing here:

```
>>> import re
>>> raceResuls = "2014 Results at:"
>>> raceDate = "Saturday, December 5, 2015"
>>> pattern = re.compile("(\d{4})")
>>> pattern.match(raceResuls).group(1)
'2014'
>>> pattern.match(raceDate).group(1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    pattern.match(raceDate).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Why does this match at the beginning of the string, but not at the end?  I am using python 2.7 on windows and linux.

Comment: Use `search` instead of `match`, the latter is anchored at the beginning of the string.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects

Comment: @Maroun  That's the trick, thanks!  If you put that into a answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @XavierAshe, that's not a trick, the definition `match` is to search only in the beggining. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match

Comment: @XavierAshe Added answer with reference, I highly recommend you to go through the link.

Comment: Thanks.  This is where I got stuck late last night and just forgot about `search`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) instead of [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match). According to the docs:

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: `re.match()` checks for a match **only at the beginning of the string**, while `re.search()` checks for a match **anywhere in the string** (this is what Perl does by default).

So when you use `match` it's the same as using [`^`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) in your regex (matches the position before the first character in the string).